# Notation: Δu and Δv in the context of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, notation

In the context of complex number functions, what do $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ mean?

I think it has something to do with partial derivatives and holomorphic or harmonic functions, but I can't find this notation anywhere except some exercises which give me no more clues about it.

Comment: It is the Laplacian.

Comment: Laplacian of $u$ and then of $v.$ If there are the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function, the Laplacians are zero.

Comment: Ok, so nothing special. Should have thought about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that this question has an answer: $\Delta$ is the Laplacian, i.e.

$$ \Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}.$$

(Or however many variables you have.)

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to ask you to post it as an answer so I can close the question :)